# Braze Connected_Content: configure a public header

Tags: liquid

**Overview**

Currently, I am attempting to use Braze's connected_content functionality to make a request to a REST API endpoint.  However, that endpoint requires the request to have a custom "Authorization" header which I can set to be the token we were given from our vendor.  I looked through the Braze documentation and it was not helpful.  We found methods to configure the body.  i.e.

```
{% connected_content https://path/to/rest/endpoint :body parameter1=param&parameter2=param2 %}
```

however, there are no methods to configure the headers.  Has anyone else ran into this problem?  I know Braze offers the ability to use Basic Auth but the website I want to use does not support that.  Has anyone solved this problem before, we have tried asking Braze this question but they have been unresponsive?

Here is a link to their connected_content documentation for reference.
https://www.braze.com/docs/user_guide/personalization_and_dynamic_content/connected_content/about_connected_content/

**Other notes**

Connected_content uses the liquid template language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to include custom headers. You must include `:headers` and include the headers between brazers

It is an example to include custom headers:

```
{% connected_content https://this.is.a/custom/url :headers {"custom": "header", "accept-language": "en-US", "accept": "application/json"} :save result %}
```